# How to capitalize ONLY the first letter of an HTML option element using CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

`text-transform: capitalize` does not work in this case because the text is already uppercase.

```
<select>
    <option>
      OPTION
    </option>
</select>
```

This did not work either.

```
select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: inline;
}

select option::first-letter{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

It should work on Chrome (at least) using CSS (and not JS).

Comment: I don't think you can do this with *only* CSS.

Comment: You can't style `<option>`

Answer (score 7):

In Chrome and Firefox, you can style an `option` element *if* its `select` has a size greater than 1.

You can exploit this as follows:

```css
select {
  height: 1.4em;             /* show only one option when not focused */
}

select:focus {
  height: 100%;              /* show all options when focused */
}

option  {
  text-transform: lowercase; /* change to lowercase */
  padding-right: 2em;        /* the select's width is based on width of its longest non-transformed ... */
                             /* option.  padding ensures that option is completely visible */
  display: none;             /* hide all options by default (see below) */
}

option::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase; /* change first letter to uppercase */
}

option:checked, select:focus option { 
  display: block;            /* show selected option, or show all options when the select is focused */
}
```

```html
<select size="4">
  <option selected>NOW IS THE TIME</option>
  <option>for all good men</option>
  <option>tO Come To tHe aid</option>
  <option>of the party</option>
</select>
```

It won't *quite* act like a normal select box, and Chrome has a strange behavior in that the selected option will have a gray background.  Can't figure out how to prevent that.

Comment: This is interesting.. Seems to work in Firefox and Chrome but not IE9 (big surprise). It might work in other versions of IE though. Anyways, I removed my answer cause it seems there is a way to do this with just CSS....

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work in IE11 either (or Safari).  I focused on Chrome based on OP's requirement, "It should work on Chrome (at least)."  There probably isn't a way to do this in IE or Safari.

Comment: I just only works in Chrome.

Comment: Hi @SalahAdDin, it still works in Firefox on Windows for me.  What OS are you running?

Comment: It is not working for me in OsX, last version.

Comment: Got it, not surprising it varies per OS.  Just a fluke it works on Windows.