# How to capitalize the first letter in the select option using css

Tags: html, css

Need to capitalize the first letter of the select box option tag.

Here it is what tried:

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option class="selected">test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
  <option>test3</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select option.selected::first-letter{
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: possible some answer dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188117/how-to-capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-an-html-option-element-using-css

Comment: Just `select {text-transform:capitalize}` should work.

Here is a Working Fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jf0ahqvo/embedded/result/

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate question. Because here OP want selected option first letter capital only.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code. if you want selected option capitalized as well then you can do as below code in HTML. This should work in most browsers.

```
select option {
  text-transform: capitalize;
 }

<select>
  <option class="selected">Test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
  <option>test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188117/how-to-capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-an-html-option-element-using-css

Comment: @Prajwal, its ok that you copied the code from another user but atleast add some line to explain too.. Thanx

Comment: @Leothelion Thanks dude I do.