# How to capitalize ONLY the first letter, if the options are only in uppercase and the selection has not a specific size? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-select

I have uppercase `option` values and I want to capitalize only the first letter.

My code:

```css
option {
  text-transform: lowercase; /* change to lowercase */
}

option::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase; /* change first letter to uppercase */
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected>ABC</option>
  <option>DEF</option>
  <option>GHI</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can use option{text-transform:capitalize;}

Comment: But why is the HTML in caps?

Comment: I found this. [lower-case-all-then-capitalize-pure-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827377/lower-case-all-then-capitalize-pure-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize ONLY the first letter of an HTML option element using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188117/how-to-capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-an-html-option-element-using-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188117/how-to-capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-an-html-option-element-using-css

Comment: it is not the same, because the solution use select option element with specific size. When you delete the size, then it not works anymore.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `option:first-letter` for this, check updated snippet below..

```css
select option  {
  text-transform: lowercase; /* change to lowercase */
}
select option:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected>ABC</option>
  <option>DEF</option>
  <option>GHI</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `text-transform:capitalize;`

Comment: I don't think this will work in this case. This will only capitalize the first character, but it will not convert the other ones to lowercase. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5of3sa6b/)

```
    select {text-transform: capitalize}
```

Comment: Can you change your Options to "ABC" "EFF" ... and test it again?

Comment: styling dropdowns tend to always be a pain.  I suggest creating your dropdown using divs and class to style to your hearts desire or using javascript.